# parse output from running wget command

Tags: awk, grep, pipe, stdout, wget

I'm using `wget` to synchronise my repository server (I know, `wget` is not the best tool, but company policy forces me...).
This is the `wget` command:

```
/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate -r -N -np -nH --cut-dirs=2 --include-directories=dir_1/dir_2/RPMS.all https://repo_url/dir_1/dir_2/RPMS.all
```

This does the job, but I would like to capture the output of `wget` which looks like this (e.g.) :

```
 --2016-07-07 16:59:10--  https://repo_url/dir_1/dir_2/RPMS.all/repodata/d65d6fc4c2a0500803acde0525aa3e604a5ea03ac7b11c5694cc8b1de08ce7cc-filelists.xml.gz
Reusing existing connection to repo_url:443.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 156605 (153K) [application/octet-stream]
Server file no newer than local file ‘RPMS.all/repodata/d65d6fc4c2a0500803acde0525aa3e604a5ea03ac7b11c5694cc8b1de08ce7cc-filelists.xml.gz’ -- not retrieving.
```

so I can process this output (using `grep`, `awk` or whatever) and show only the current file that I'm `wget`-ing.

Apart from that, I want to display that output on the same line over and over until finished (maybe even discarding the 'no newer' files, like above.

I tried several solutions I found (e.g. using `IFS` or `shopt` or stdbuf), but none seem to work. I also tried with the `wget -O -` option, but that doesn't work either.

Maybe to clarify a bit more:
I'd like to do this while `wget` is working. I don't want to do this when `wget` is finished, but process each connection while `wget` is running, whether the source file is newer or not.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Maybe you can try wget in background and sed.( wget foobar 2> file.txt  & sed -n 6p file.txt).